# Google Material Charts (Bar) - NumberFormat() not working

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api

I'm trying out the new material charts from google and they are excellent, except for one thing - I can't format the data numbers. For example I want the tooltips to say $58.00 instead of 58.

```
// Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', '');
        data.addColumn('number', '');
        data.addRows(chart_raw_data);

        // Format
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({decimalSymbol: ',',groupingSymbol: '.', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, prefix: '$'});
        formatter.format(data, 1);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
            'chartArea' : { left : 0, top : 0, width : '100%', height : '100%' },
            'legend' : { position : 'none' }
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('earnings_last_30_days'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
```

I have tried removing 'chartArea' and 'legend' from the options, they aren't the issue.
Also if I console.log the "data" array after the formatter, I can see that the values in column 1 are now like this:

```
{ v : '58', f : '$58.00' }
```

But it always shows the 'v', instead of 'f'. I also couldn't find any examples in the documentation where they show a material chart with formatted number.

Any ideas?

Comment: Appears to be a reported bug.  See https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1946